# Python 3 Derivative Approximation Errors with loglog plot

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, enumerate, derivative, loglog

I need some help understanding this. I watched this YouTube video 
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5pwy1NZqbM) that shows how to graph derivative approximation errors on a loglog plot. I get what the final graph shows, but I'm not sure what is going on in the for loop of the script. Here is the script in full:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return np.exp(-x**2)

def f_diff(x):
    return -2*x*np.exp(-x**2)

def center(x,h):
    return(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2*h)

def forward(x,h):
    return (f(x+h)-f(x))/h

def backward(x,h):
    return (f(x)-f(x-h))/h

def third_approx(x,h):
    return (2*f(x+h)+3*f(x)-6*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(6*h)

x0 = 0.2
h_vector = [10**(-temp) for temp in np.arange(0,17,0.1)]
forward_result = np.zeros(len(h_vector))
center_result = np.zeros(len(h_vector))
backward_result = np.zeros(len(h_vector))
third_approx_result = np.zeros(len(h_vector))
true_result = np.zeros(len(h_vector))

for index, i in enumerate(h_vector):
    forward_result[index] = forward(x0,i)
    center_result[index] = center(x0,i)
    backward_result[index] = backward(x0,i)
    third_approx_result[index] = third_approx(x0,i)
    true_result[index] = f_diff(x0)

plt.figure()
plt.loglog(h_vector, abs(forward_result-true_result),label ='Forward')
plt.loglog(h_vector, abs(center_result-true_result),label='Center')
plt.loglog(h_vector, abs(backward_result-true_result),label='Backward')
plt.loglog(h_vector, abs(third_approx_result-true_result),label='third_approx')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('h')
plt.ylabel('Absolute difference')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The for loop is really confusing to me. This is what I'm used to:

```
x = np.arange(0,10,0.1) #could also use np.linspace
n = x.size
dx = 0.1
FD = np.zeros(n)
BD = np.zeros(n)
CD = np.zeros(n)
third = np.zeros(n)
exact = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    FD[i] = forward(x[i],dx)
    BD[i] = backward(x[i],dx)
    CD[i] = center(x[i],dx)
    third[i] = third_approx(x[i],dx)
    exact[i] = df(dx)
```

I have never seen a for loop that says "for index, i in enumerate(x):" Why does it say "for index" rather than "for i in range"? What is enumerate? And how do I translate this into a for loop that I'm more familiar with?

Comment: Edit: the math equation used in the video is different than what is in the full script. I replaced it with an equation that I'm trying to work with.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with my professor, I can answer my own question. The original for loop is rather confusing for most people, but it can be made into a loop that most people can recognize. First, to coincide with a loglog plot, the x-space is made negative and used as an exponent of 10. Then, all the function that use this new space, called h_vector, are indexed to the length of h_vector, as well as the for loop. In the first line of the for loop, set a variable dx equal to the indexed h_vector. Here is the full script for this problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return np.exp(-x**2)

def df(x):
    return -2*x*np.exp(-x**2)

def center(f,x,h):
    return(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2*h)

def forward(f,x,h):
    return (f(x+h)-f(x))/h

def backward(f,x,h):
    return (f(x)-f(x-h))/h

def third_approx(f,x,h):
    return (2*f(x+h)+3*f(x)-6*f(x-h)+f(x-2*h))/(6*h)

x = np.linspace(0,3,100)
x0 = 0.2
h_vector = [10**(-temp) for temp in np.arange(0,17,0.1)]
nh = len(h_vector)
FD = np.zeros(nh)
BD = np.zeros(nh)
CD = np.zeros(nh)
third = np.zeros(nh)
exact = np.zeros(nh)

for i in range(nh):
    dx = h_vector[i]
    FD[i] = forward(f,x0,dx)
    BD[i] = backward(f,x0,dx)
    CD[i] = center(f,x0,dx)
    third[i] = third_approx(f,x0,dx)
    exact[i] = df(x0)

plt.figure()
plt.title('e^(-x^2) and Derivative')
plt.plot(x,f(x),label='e^(-x^2)')
plt.plot(x,df(x),label='df/dx(e^(-x^2))')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.title('Difference between Derivative Approximations and Exact Value')
plt.loglog(h_vector,abs(FD-exact),label='Forward difference')
plt.loglog(h_vector,abs(BD-exact),label='Backward difference')
plt.loglog(h_vector,abs(CD-exact),label='Center difference')
plt.loglog(h_vector,abs(third-exact),label='Exact value')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('10^(-x)')
plt.ylabel('10^(-y)')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Note the differences between this script and the original above. The derivative approximations are in terms of three variables: f, x, and h. In the for loop, they are in terms of f, x0, and dx, which correspond to f, x, and h.

This script can be used with any equation in x and y. Just write the equation in the f(x) function and its derivative in the df(x) function.